# SQL Reporting Services - Parameters at the top display in wrong format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When I choose the data parameters for a report on my Reporting Services Server, while it returns the correct data it displays the date in US Format.

Note this is the parameters at the top and NOT how they display on the report, the report definition strictly states en-GB so the dates on the report are in the correct format.

The server's locale/language is set to English (United Kingdom) can anyone point me in the right direction of changing the Reporting Services to English UK also?

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "at the top and not on the report"? May be it's a case to add a picture to your question?

Comment: @sepupic "At the top" as in where you select your parameters or input your parameters i.e. a Date